# increase value to a point, then start decreasing to a point

Tags: javascript, canvas

I am making a simple animation in javascript canvas and in order to accomplish the requested result i need to have an object like this:

```
circle: {
    x: scene_point.x,
    y: scene_point.y,
    vel_x: randomFloat(0.100, 0.500),
    vel_y: randomFloat(0.100, 0.500),
    r: 0,
    r_max: 10,
    trend: 'up'
}
```

now animation in loop should be like this:

1. increase value of radius till it get max, increase opacity until circle become fully visible
2. when circle has max radius and full opacity, we start to decreasing both values
3. when circle radius and opacity again go down to 0, we reset circle and start over.

this is the code i written to accomplish above:

```
if(circle.trend === 'up' && circle.r < circle.maxR) { // growing, to reach max
    circle.r = parseFloat(circle.r) + parseFloat(circle.decayR);
}
if(circle.trend === 'up' && circle.r >= circle.maxR) { // reached max, starting to decay
    circle.trend = 'down';
}
if(circle.trend === 'down' && circle.r >= 1) { // decaying, to reach min
    circle.r = parseFloat(circle.r) - parseFloat(circle.decayR);
}
if(circle.trend === 'down' && circle.r < 1) { // reached min, reseting
    reset(i);
}
```

and finally draw object to get proper opacity:

```
ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(210, 210, 210, ' + circle.r / circle.maxR + ')';
```

The question is, is it possible to accomplish above without "trend" logic, its just doesnt seem / feel right. I have to use 4 if conditions and additional "trend" parameter to just go up and down. Maybe there is more friendly way to do it. I am just new to the canvas and animations and i dont know all the tricks yet ;)

Comment: why `parseFloat` for numbers?

Comment: You may create field `state` with an integer inside, instead of `trend`. So, you will start from 0 - 'up', then 1 - 'down', then something else (new behaviour). You need the state (or trend) anyway. It's like in the turing machines, you know :)

Comment: i had some problems with getting float value. without parsing i was getting 1 or 2, while when i parse float i got 1.032 and so on

Comment: You could also have a "velocity" or "increment" for the radius and opacity, adding that to the value, and simply negate it when either extreme is met.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just do:

```
circle.r += circle.decayR;

if(circle.decayR > 0 && circle.r >= circle.maxR)
  circle.decayR *= -1;

if(circle.decayR < 0 && circle.r < 1)
  reset(i);
```

Basically, just flip the sign of the `decayR`.

Working example:

```js
var circle, canvas, ctx;

canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

function reset() {
  circle = {
    decayR: 1,
    r: 0,
    maxR: 20,
    x: 50 + Math.random() * 50,
    y: 50 + Math.random() * 50
  };
}

function update() {
  circle.r += circle.decayR;

  if (circle.decayR > 0 && circle.r >= circle.maxR)
    circle.decayR *= -1;

  if (circle.decayR < 0 && circle.r < 1)
    reset();

  // clear
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

  // draw
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(circle.x, circle.y, circle.r, 0, Math.PI * 2);
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.fill();

  requestAnimationFrame(update);
}

reset();

requestAnimationFrame(update);
```

```css
#canvas {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: solid 1px black;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="200" height="200"></canvas>
```

Comment: i like the idea very much, but this particular code, doesnt do anything, i mean there are no errors but nothing is being drawed either. i am trying to figure out why

Answer (score 0):

I think it can be put shorter like this:

```
if(circle.trend === 'up'){
  (circle.r >= circle.maxR) ?
    circle.trend = 'down' :
    circle.r += circle.decayR; 
}else{
  (circle.r >= 1) ?
    circle.r -= circle.decayR :
    reset(i);
}
```